# SQL Query - Range two dates - including nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which includes customer transactions. These transactions could have `StartDate` and `EndDate`. If the `EndDate` hasn't come, then the field is NULL. In my query, if I select for example the transactions that started today and don't have enddate (which is `NULL`) I don't get the right results. However, if I set the `@EndDate` as tomorrow, then I get the result. Any ideas?

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(Buyin), 0) AS CountBuyIns
FROM [Transaction] AS t
WHERE (t.StartDate >= @StartDate) AND (ISNULL(t.EndTime,GETDATE()) <= @EndDate)
```

Comment: What data types are `t.StartDate`, `t.EndDate`, `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND (t.EndTime <= @EndDate OR t.EndTime IS NULL)
```

or:

```
AND COALESCE(t.EndTime, @EndDate) <= @EndDate
```

Comment: The first one is far better. The second option is nonSARGable.

Comment: @SeanLange: Few queries will use an index for a date range.  The query analyzer tries to avoid index lookups and prefers a table scan.  Sargeability for date ranges is overrated.

Comment: That is not the case in my experience. Do you have any references or examples to demonstrate that?

Comment: that is interesting. I will look closer at index usage on date(time) columns over the next few days and see what I find. The example there is awfully simple but it is certainly interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last part of the WHERE clause like so

```
AND t.EndTime IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want all records returned after the start date if you don't select an @EndDate.  To do that it would be simplest to wrap @EndDate in an ISNULL as well.

```
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(Buyin), 0) AS CountBuyIns
FROM [Transaction] AS t
WHERE (t.StartDate >= @StartDate) AND (ISNULL(t.EndTime,GETDATE()) <= 
ISNULL(@EndDate, GETDATE()))
```

This way, if @EndDate is null, you use todays date.  If this doesn't work because you have valid EndDates that come over today, then you can use an or.

```
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(Buyin), 0) AS CountBuyIns
FROM [Transaction] AS t
WHERE (t.StartDate >= @StartDate) AND (ISNULL(t.EndTime,GETDATE()) <= 
@EndDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
```